# Cuploadfile instance not compared to null although no file instance is provided?

Tags: yii, upload

```
public function actionCreate()
{
       $model=new Patient('patientScenario');
       if(isset($_POST['Patient']))
        {
$model->attributes=$_POST['Patient'];
$model->image=  CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
if($model->save())
{
$imagePath = Yii::app()->params['DataFolder'];
if($model->image!="")
              { 
              if(!(file_exists($imagePath)))    
             {
                   mkdir($imagePath,'0777',true);
             }
             }
         $model->image->saveAs($imagePath.$model->id.'_'.$model->image->name);
         $ns=new newserver();                                       $ns->uploadFile($filepath,$imagePath.$model->id.'_'.$model->image->name, $model->id.'_'.$model->image->name);
}
          }}
```

It is a action with lot of codes I have simplified it to focus on the issue here.

The issue is while creating a patient, If I upload a image its working fine, But even though I don't upload an image the condition $model->image!="" became true and obviously there will be no file name and while trying to upload on the new server class I get

```
fopen(22522_): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I tried ($model->image!==NULL) as well. still getting the same error.
But it works fine in my localhost, But not in the server.

Comment: so echo or print_r $model->image and see its value :)

Comment: I tried it on the server, it didn't print anything. But unexpectedly it came back to normal, We didn't change any single line of code but it started to work fine. Still don't have any idea, how it went like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is on newserver() class

On that class you are tried to open a file .
Check condition before the file open on newserver() class

or give a code on newserver Class